# how to split a string with both space and special characters in oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substring

I want to split the string by space and with special characters if any.
Ex: For expressing mobile switching center (signal strength).

Currently I am using the regex to split the string and I am not able to achieve both space and special characters split.

```
insert into tmp(word)
    select     regexp_substr('For expressing mobile switching center 
    (signal strength).', '(.*?)([[:space:]]|$)', 1, level, null, 1 ) as token
    from       dual
    connect by level <= regexp_count('For expressing mobile switching center (signal strength).', '[[:space:]/:]+') + 1
```

```
CREATE TABLE TMP(WORD VARCHAR2(4000));

Current Output: For
expressing
mobile
switching
center
(signal
strength).
```

```
Expected Output: For
expressing
mobile
switching
center
(
signal
strength
)
.
```

Updated Code:

```
insert into tmp(word)
select     regexp_substr('For expressing mobile switching center (signal strength).', '(.*?)([[:space:]()]|$)', 1, level, null, 1 ) as token
from       dual
connect by level <= regexp_count('For expressing mobile switching center (signal strength).', '(.*?)([[:space:]()]|$)')+ 1

Result:
For
expressing
mobile
switching
center
(null)
signal
strength
.
(null)
(null)
```

Comment: you need to include `()` in you character class, [`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/BcdAKM/1/)

Comment: I tried this and updated the code above. Looks like I still need to modify. Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 0):

This is DB2 but hopefully you can translate it:

```
with data (s) as (values
('For expressing mobile switching center (signal strength).')
),
     tally (n) as (
select row_number() over (order by 1)
from   (values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) x (n)
cross  join (values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) y (n)
)
select regexp_substr(s,'([A-Za-z]+|\(|\)|\.)', 1, n)
from   data
cross  join tally 
where  n <= regexp_count(s,'([A-Za-z]+|\(|\)|\.)')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your regexp so it's searching for (a) a parenthesis character or (b) a series of characters which aren't spaces or parentheses.

```
select     regexp_substr('For expressing mobile switching center (signal strength).', '[()]|[^[:space:]()]+', 1, level, null) as token
from       dual
connect by level <= regexp_count('For expressing mobile switching center (signal strength).', '[()]|[^[:space:]()]+');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will split at any character that is not alpha or numeric:

```
WITH
    aset AS( SELECT 'abc def;ghi|hkl () 0W-' AS tobesplit FROM DUAL ),
    splitup ( VALUE, rest ) AS
        (SELECT SUBSTR( tobesplit
                      , 1
                      , REGEXP_INSTR( tobesplit || ' ',  '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' ) - 1 )
              , SUBSTR( tobesplit, REGEXP_INSTR( tobesplit || ' ',  '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' ) + 1 ) || ' '
           FROM aset
         UNION ALL
         SELECT SUBSTR( rest
                      , 1
                      , REGEXP_INSTR( rest,  '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' ) - 1 )
              , SUBSTR( rest, REGEXP_INSTR( rest || ' ',  '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' ) + 1 )
           FROM splitup
          WHERE rest IS NOT NULL)
SELECT value 
  FROM splitup where value is not null;
```